# What does Laravel do with the additional session metadata?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.3

I am currently working on session handling of my own and I am looking at the Laravel session table which looks like this:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->integer('user_id')->nullable();
    $table->string('ip_address', 45)->nullable();
    $table->text('user_agent')->nullable();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

I understand the `id`, `payload`, `user_id` and `last_activity` but what are the `ip_address` and `user_agent` used for?

What does Laravel do exactly with these 2 attributes? How do they come into play. Are they checked when Laravel does something with the session? What is their exact use?

Cheers.

Comment: One usage of `ip_address` is for throttling requests. `user_agent` is just for logging purposes.